# ios9 black splash screen when using localized

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

When I download my app in appstore, I'm using iOS9. 
My app lost splash screen, instead of black screen and screen size as iphone 4.
I don't use asset catalog.
How can I fix it? Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

To resize for each iPhone you have to **use asset catalog**.Use asset catalog and specify launch files for each device.This will solve your problem.

Comment: but when I use asset catalog. I don't localize splash screen. Do you have any idea to help me?